# How to compare an ASCII value

Tags: c, file, text, ascii, file-read

I want to store the ASCII value of a letter into a variable, how can I do this?

for example :

```
r ASCII variable = 82
main()
{
    character = "character read from a file";
    variable= "r ascii"; //(in this case 82), the problem is that the letter is always        variable.;
    printf( "the value of %c is %d, character, variable)
}
```

How can I do this?

Also on an extra note, how could I read a `.txt` file character by character? so It could be saved on the character variable.

Answer (score 14):

Just do:

```
if (r == 82) {
   // provided r is a char or int variable
}
```

In **C**, `char` variables are represented by their **ASCII** integer value, so, if you have this:

```
char r;
r = 82;
if (r == 82) {
}
```

Is the same as:

```
char r;
r = 'R';
if (r == 'R') { // 'R' value is 82

}
```

You can even mix them:

```
char r;
r = 82;
if (r == 'R') { // will be true

}
```

Comment: In C, variables are not _necessarily_ ASCII, only for about 99.9% of the machines out there is this true and I, unfortunately, do work on one of the others :-)

Comment: USS/OMVS/(whatever it's called this week) on the mainframe uses EBCDIC.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to save the `ascii` value onto an integer variable

just use this

```
int b;
char c = 'r';
b = (int)c;
printf("%d",b);
```