# Immediate exit of a loop when input is not an unsigned in C++

Tags: c++, loops

My code is:

```
unsigned numbers, x = 0, odds = 0;
cout << "Input numbers to find the amount of odds. " << endl;
while ( x < 9999 ){
    cin >> numbers || die("Input Error");
    if (numbers % 2 == 1) {
        odds++;
    }
}
cout << "There are " << odds << " odds." << endl;

return 0;
```

How can I quit the loop when the user inputs a non-numeric value for numbers? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading 'unsigned int' using 'cin'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574771/reading-unsigned-int-using-cin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the input a condition of the loop.

```
while (cin >> numbers)
{
    //...
}
```

Will run until the user enters something that cannot be inputted into `numbers`.  If you want to have the check the `numbers < 9999` as well then we would have

```
while (std::cin >> numbers && numbers < 9999)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: this is incorrect. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465494/how-to-compare-an-ascii-value

Comment: @Nandu What?  That has nothing to do with this and it is wrong language.

Comment: @Nandu The question was "How can I quit the loop when the user inputs a non-numeric value for numbers?" How is "123a" a numeric value?

Comment: @Nandu It will pick up the 123 and then terminate after processing it.  This as good as the OP can get without doing a bunch of string processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cctype>
std::string str;
cin >> str;
for ( std::string::iterator it=str.begin(); it!=str.end(); ++it)
 if (!std::isdigit(*it)) {
   cout << "non-digit");
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you are looking for is `break`:

```
while ( x < 9999 ) {
    if((cin >> numbers).fail())
        break;

    if (numbers % 2 == 1) {
        odds++;
    }
}
```

Comment: incorrect. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465494/how-to-compare-an-ascii-value

Comment: @Nandu can you please elaborate, why you think, this is incorrect? Your link is completely unrelated to the question and to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use hash_fun to evaluate the strings and ingnore any non numeric values

Comment: What is a `hash_fun` and how to use it? Please, improve your answer.